# Not recognized as an internal or external command when running Prefect Agent on my Local Machine. Need help on how to resolve this

Tags: prefect

I'm trying to run a prefect agent on my local machine that's connected to a prefect cloud. Whenever I try to execute a flow from the cloud ui, I get this internal or external command not found error in the CLI where the agent is running. Could anyone help me resolve this?

---

| _ \ _ \ **| **| **/ **|*   *|   /*\ / **| _*| | |*   *|
|  */   / *|| *|| *| (**  | |    / _ \ (* | *|| .` | | |
|*| |*|*_**|*| |**__**| |*|   /*/ __**|__*|*|_| |_|

Agent started! Looking for work from queue(s): dev...

22:06:05.946 | INFO    | prefect.agent - Submitting flow run 'a33036c2-2bea-4a3a-9ce8-8317b4966923'

22:06:06.803 | INFO    | prefect.infrastructure.process - Opening process 'organic-jaybird'...

22:06:06.843 | INFO    | prefect.agent - Completed submission of flow run 'a33036c2-2bea-4a3a-9ce8-8317b4966923'

'C:\Users*******\OneDrive' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your agent or your deployment is running from a OneDrive drive path which might not work properly. How did you create a deployment? Does your flow run fine when you execute it without a deployment? What Prefect version are you using? the command `prefect version` might help find that

We have some resources here that might help as well: https://discourse.prefect.io/t/prefect-deployments-faq-pdf/1467

Comment: I actually did the basic deployment creation with python using 3 basic configurations: flow, name, and work_queue_name. The flow just works fine without a deployment, and I'm using the latest version 2.6.4. Before this version though, I can run flows successfully in cloud ui. I also tried to trigger a deployment using this command: prefect deployment run sampleflow/dev but it keeps on failing. Below is exception I got from trying to run a deployment.

Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000002461CAC4430> 

RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Comment: You may try removing the local Orion db: `rm ~/.prefect/orion.db`, starting from scratch prefect orion start``and see if this solves it